# How to Store subvariables and functions in a variable, in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, variables

I looked everywhere in google to find this, maybe It's not even possible to do this in Python. Any ideas?

In JavaScript I could do:

```
var variable = {
    name:       'It has a name',
    Function: function(wow) {
        //todo
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually in Python you would use a `class` for that. What is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a `dict` to use in this way if you want

```
def foo():
    return 5   

var = {'name': 'foo', 'function': foo}

>>> var['name']             # accessing the name
'foo'

>>> var['function']         # accessing the function
<function foo at 0x02E68C00>

>>> var['function']()       # calling the function
5
```

Calling a function with a parameter

```
def bar(x):
    return x+5

var = {'name': 'something', 'function': bar}

>>> var['function'](7)
12
```

Comment: How would you pass parameters to the function? var['function'](param1) ?